# Can't get jquery plug-in to work with simple html test

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, web

Fairly new to javascript/jquery and html here.

I was trying to demo the vegas JQuery plug-in found [here](http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/documentation/setup/), but I can't get the background to show up.

My test page root has the folders: css, images, js, vegas.

From what I understand, to get jQuery to work, I downloaded the .js file from the jQuery homepage and then put that .js file into my js folder that I made for my test page.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks ahead of time.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>backgroundTest</title>

            <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/vegas/jquery.vegas.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/vegas/jquery.vegas.css"/>

            <script>    

            $(function() {
              $.vegas({
                src:'/images/abstract.jpg'
              });
              $.vegas('overlay', {
                src:'/vegas/overlays/13.png'
              });
            });
            </script>

        </head>

        <body>

            <p>
            Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
            ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
            amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut
            odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
            </p>

        </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Install FireBug and check the console for any errors. Also, try your code in JSFiddle.

Comment: Ahh, just checked both of those out. Thank you for the tips!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote code for vegas slider please note that I load JS and CSS using CDN.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Test</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://jaysalvat.github.io/vegas/releases/latest/jquery.vegas.min.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jaysalvat.github.io/vegas/releases/latest/jquery.vegas.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function () {

                $.vegas('slideshow', {
                    backgrounds: [
                        { src: 'images/1.png', fade: 1000 },
                        { src: 'images/2.png', fade: 1000 }
                    ]
                })('overlay');});
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```